# Trouble Centering Divs

Tags: html, css, center

I've been having trouble center 3 divs on my webpage. I have tried using auto margin and inline-block lines in the css, but nothing is seeming to work. I have borders on the divs temporarily to make it easier to see the divs. But, when I try and apply any sort of centering, the divs stay on the left. If anyone could get all 3 of the following divs to be centered, that would be great, as I'm quite new to html and css coding. Thanks in advance! Here's the page:

```
        <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Vortex Network</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Luckiest+Guy' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style type="text/css">

#top-image {

    background:url('https://www.14denoviembre.es/img/stars_5.png') -25px -50px;
    position:fixed ;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
    z-index:98;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
     #top-image {
        width:20%;
        height:20%;

    }
}

body { 

    color:#FFF; 
    height:55%; 
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    color:#FFF;
    min-width:100%; 
    width: auto !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }

.stars {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url( http://www.14denoviembre.es/img/hori.png ), url(     http://www.14denoviembre.es/img/stars_5.png ); 
    background-repeat: repeat-x,repeat-x repeat-y;
    transform:translate3D(0em, 0em, 0); 
    animation: stars 21s ease; 
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

      }


.Icon {

    width: 710px;
    height: 450px;
    top: 5%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: auto;


    }

#thumbs {   
    border-style: solid;
    position: absolute;
    width: 925px;
    top: 55%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;

}
.status {   
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px  solid #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    top:  77%;
    margin: auto;
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 75px #ffffff;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 75px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 75px #ffffff;

   }

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 5;
}
.floating{
    -webkit-animation-name: Floatingx;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: Floating;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

@-webkit-keyframes Floatingx{
    from {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-webkit-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-webkit-transform: translate(0, -0px);    }    
}

@-moz-keyframes Floating{
    from {-moz-transform:translate(0, 0px);}
    65% {-moz-transform:translate(0, 15px);}
    to {-moz-transform: translate(0, -0px);}    
}


.scaling{
    float: center;
    -webkit-animation-name: scalex;
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-name: scale;
    -moz-animation-duration:3s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
}

    @-webkit-keyframes scalex{
        from {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);}
        65% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.0);}
        to {-webkit-transform: scale(0.9);}    
    }

    @-moz-keyframes scale{
        from {-moz-transform: scale(0.9);}
        65% {-moz-transform: scale(1.0);}
        to {-moz-transform: scale(0.9);}    
    }
.zoom_img img{  
-moz-transition:-moz-transform 0.2s ease-in; 
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in; 
-o-transition:-o-transform 0.2s ease-in;
}
.zoom_img img:hover{
-moz-transform:scale(1.1); 
-webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
-o-transform:scale(1.1);
}
.shadowfilter {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.80));
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;

}

.shadowfilter:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 8px rgba(255, 255, 179, 0.8));
}
p {
    font-family: 'Luckiest Guy', cursive;
      -webkit-text-stroke: 3px black;
       color: #ae00de;
       font-size: 2.6em;
       margin:0px;
}
</style>
</head>
<script>
    (function(){
      ShootingStar = function( id ) {
        this.n = 0;
        this.m = 0;
        this.defaultOptions = { velocity:8, starSize:10, life:300, beamSize:400, dir:-1 };
        this.options = {};
        id = ( typeof id != "undefined" )?id:"";
        this.capa = ( $( id ).lenght > 0 )?"body":id;
        this.wW = $( this.capa ).innerWidth();
        this.hW = $( this.capa ).innerHeight();
      };

      ShootingStar.prototype.addBeamPart = function( x, y ) {
        this.n++;
        var name = this.getRandom( 100, 1 );
        $( "#star"+name ).remove();
        $( this.capa ).append( "<div id='star"+name+"'></div>" );
        $( "#star"+name ).append( "<div id='haz"+this.n+"' class='haz' style='position:absolute; color:#FF0; width:10px; height:10px; font-weight:bold; font-size:"+this.options.starSize+"px'>·</div>" );
        if ( this.n > 1 ) $( "#haz" + ( this.n - 1 ) ).css( { color:"rgba(255,255,255,0.5)" } );
        $( "#haz" + this.n ).css( { top: y + this.n, left: x + ( this.n * this.options.dir ) } );
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.delTrozoHaz = function() {
        this.m++;
        $( "#haz" + this.m ).animate( {opacity:0}, 75 );
        if ( this.m >= this.options.beamSize ) { $( "#ShootingStarParams" ).fadeOut( "slow" ); }
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.getRandom = function( max, min ) {
        return Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.toType = function ( obj ) {
        if ( typeof obj === "undefined" ) { return "undefined"; /* consider: typeof null === object */ }
        if ( obj === null ) { return "null"; }
        var type = Object.prototype.toString.call( obj ).match( /^\[object\s(.*)\]$/ )[1] || '';
        switch ( type ) {
          case 'Number': if ( isNaN( obj ) ) { return "nan"; } else { return "number"; }
          case 'String': case 'Boolean': case 'Array': case 'Date': case 'RegExp': case 'Function': return type.toLowerCase();
        }
        if ( typeof obj === "object" ) { return "object"; }
        return undefined;
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.launchStar = function( options ) {
        if ( this.toType( options ) != "object" ) { options = {}; }
        this.options = $.extend( {}, this.defaultOptions, options );
        this.n=0;
        this.m=0;
        var i=0, l=this.options.beamSize,
            x=this.getRandom( this.wW - this.options.beamSize - 100, 100 ), y=this.getRandom( this.hW - this.options.beamSize - 100, 100 ),
            self = this;
        for( ; i<l; i++ ) { setTimeout( function(){ self.addBeamPart( x, y ); }, self.options.life + ( i * self.options.velocity ) ); }
        for( i=0; i<l; i++ ) { setTimeout( function(){ self.delTrozoHaz() }, self.options.beamSize + ( i * self.options.velocity ) ); }
        $( "#ShootingStarParams" ).html();
        $( "#ShootingStarParams" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
      }

      ShootingStar.prototype.launch = function( everyTime ) {
        if ( this.toType( everyTime ) != "number" ) { everyTime = 2; }
        everyTime = everyTime * 1000;
        this.launchStar();
        var self = this;
        setInterval( function() {
          var options = {
            dir: ( self.getRandom( 1, 0 ))?1:-1,
            life: self.getRandom( 400, 100 ),
            beamSize: self.getRandom( 700, 400 ),
            velocity: self.getRandom( 10, 4 )
          }
          self.launchStar( options );
        }, everyTime );
      }

})();

</script>
<body class="stars">
            <div class="zoom_img">
                <div id="thumbs">
                <!-- Forum Icon -->
                <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/forum" id="single_image1"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/i03eeyw23/Forums_After.png" alt="Forums_Icon" height="180" width="180"/></a>
                <!-- Vote Icon -->
                <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/vote" id="single_image2"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/vshtalmtn/Vote_After.png" alt="Vote_Icon" height="180" width="180"/></a>
                <!-- Store Icon -->
                <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/donate" id="single_image3"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/j4xgkciiz/Store_After.png" alt="Shop_Icon" height="180" width="175"/></a>
                <!-- Staff Icon --> 
                <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/members" id="single_image4"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/ds8m67umj/Staff_After_2.png" alt="Staff_Icon" height="180" width="180"/></a>
                <!-- Bans Icon -->
                <a href="http://vortexpvp.com/bans" id="single_image5"><img class="shadowfilter" src="http://s15.postimg.org/5vo4xzj63/Bans_After_2.png" alt="Bans_Icon" height="180" width="180"/></a>

            </div>​
        </div>

<!-- Logo -->
<div class="Icon">
    <img src="http://files.enjin.com/353719/module_header/10950667/background/Vortex-Network-Logonew.png" class="scaling" width="642" height="460"></img>
</div> 

<!-- IP Adress -->
<div class="status">
    <p>play.vortexpvp.com</p>
</div>

<div id="top-image"></div>
    <div id="ShootingStarParams"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ShootingStarClass.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready( function(){
        var shootingStarObj = new ShootingStar( "body" );
            shootingStarObj.launch();
      });
        </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: atleast show us a picture, what you want

Comment: Well, for one, as soon as you close your script block, you are closing a div and your style block should be in the head section along with your script block. You need to organize your code correctly before you can expect anything to work properly.

Comment: It is hard to answer your question when you're not asking it correctly. What is "center" 3 divs? Horizontally, vertically?

Comment: add an image how do you want it to be placed

Comment: Sorry about being unclear. I would like the Icon div, the Status div, and the thumbs div to be centered horizontally, no matter the resolution or size of the browser. I moved the style back to the head, and removed the extra closing div.